# Event Binding does not work on <object> in Angular 2 and above

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have tried to bind to an event coming from SVG object inside Angular 6.0 template, and found that none of the events which are standard for most of the HTML Elements are not working for binding on "< object >" tag with SVG inside (if this is relevant).

```
@Component(
    {
        selector: 'loading-component',
        template: `
            SVG TEST
            <object data="mysvg.svg" type="image/svg+xml" (click)="svgClickHandler($event)"></object>`

    })
export class LoadingComponent
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log('LoadingComponent.constructor()', '');
    }

    public svgClickHandler(e: MouseEvent): void
    {
        console.log('LoadingComponent.svgClickHandler()', e);

    }
}
```

Why Angular does not make binding to events coming from  ?

Comment: have you included the forms module in your app.module?

Comment: No I have not, I am using a boilerplate Angular-Cli app. Should I include this forms module ?

Comment: you need it for data binding things such as ngModel, i think it applies to click events too

Comment: I don't think I need it since <button (click)="svgClickHandler($event)"></button> is working fine.

Comment: what is your issue then?

Comment: on <object (click)="svgClickHandler($event)" ... ></object>` it does not work, why ?

Comment: object doesnt have a click event? you could use hammerjs for this though

Comment: Tnx man I will investigate this a bit more, it seems very strange not to have click event working on < object > which have SVG inside.